# Does SQLite have Cursors?

Tags: sqlite, cursor

i wonder if i could run the following procedure in SQLite:

```
set nocount on

select T.ID, max(T.SerialNo) as SerialNo
into #Tmp_Ticket_ID
from Ticket as T, Ticket as inserted
where t.ID = inserted.ID
group by T.id having count(*) > 1

declare zeiger cursor for
    select SerialNo
    from #Tmp_Ticket_ID

declare @SerialNo int

OPEN Zeiger  
FETCH NEXT FROM zeiger INTO @SerialNo 
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)  
BEGIN  
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)  
    BEGIN  
        update T
            set ID = (select max(id) + 1 from Ticket)
        from ticket AS T, #Tmp_Ticket_ID as I
        where t.serialNo = i.serialno
        and I.Serialno = @SerialNo
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM zeiger INTO @SerialNo
END  
CLOSE Zeiger  
DEALLOCATE Zeiger  
DROP TABLE #Tmp_Ticket_ID
```

This is a little procedure from a ms-sql2000 which cleans doubles of Ticket_id's in a given table Ticket of the following structur:

```
create table Ticket (serialNo int identity(1,1) not null
    , ID as int not null
    , Ticket_issue as varchar(50)
    , some_more_field varchar(500))
```

Due to a simple merger from different databases, the ticket_id's becomes not unique. To fix by renumbering this i developed this procedure but now we have a similar issue on a SQLite-db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete from Ticket
where exists
 (select rowid from Ticket t2
   where t2.ID = Ticket.ID and t2.rowid < Ticket.rowid)
```

`rowid` is the always-present SQLite btree index column.

Thanks to Martin Engelschalk on the SQLite mailing list on 2009-08-17.

Comment: Seems not to renumber the duplicate tickets. deletion is not the solution. Have also to document the old id and the new id in a list...

Comment: OK, now that I know what you are trying to do, perhaps a 4 step process: insert the dups to a temp table using the where clause above, delete the dups as above, renumber the dups in the temp table, and insert them back.

Comment: So there are no cursors in sqlite.

Comment: Correct, there are no cursors. 
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: @DougCurrie wait there are no cursors in sqlite? Now I'm really confused!   What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177938/sqlite-cursor-never-has-fields-in-it?rq=1   Also, in python the sqlite package has cursors, I assumed latched onto sqlite cursors. I  guess I was wrong, in which case what is cursor() doing in sqlite module in python?

Comment: SQL cursors have many features that are not supported by SQLite (did you read the SQLite web page on cursors that I referenced?). Many of these operations are described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases) and include FETCH (seeking, scrolling), UPDATE and DELETE through a CURSOR, etc. Python may support cursors for other databases (I don't know), and fake it for SQLite using the usual SQLite mechanism of stepping through a result set.

Comment: @Doug I looked at that page but it didn't seem a very direct answer to the general question, at least to this noob. E.g., maybe I missed it, but I didn't see where it directly came out with "cursors are not possible in sqlite". But I am not familiar with cursors, so maybe it answered it indirectly with the stuff about stepping back in a result set or something.