# SQLite Cursor never has fields in it

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to retrieve fields from a table in a SQLite database. I've verified that the data is in the table by using the sqlite3 command and running the query which I got out of the Cursor using the debugger against the database referenced inside my "database" object.

Here is my code:

```
openForRead();

Cursor cursor = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            null, // All columns
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "((" + latitude + " - " + KEY_LAT + ") * (" + latitude + " - " + KEY_LAT + ") + ( "
                    + longitude + " - " + KEY_LONG + ") * ( " + longitude + " - "+ KEY_LONG + "))",
            "10"
);

close();
```

This code generates a SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM airport ORDER BY ((35.9314068 - latitude) * (35.9314068 - latitude) + ( -115.09285366 - longitude) * ( -115.09285366 - longitude)) LIMIT 10
```

I only have 5 airports in the table right now, so I'm not going over some memory limit or anything like that.

When I run that query in sqlite3 I get the data back.

Why is my Cursor always empty? It's empty even if I set everything to null (which should just return everything..)

Comment: giving more info would definitely help, can u paste a snippet of your codes at least we know which part is empty. u meant cursor.size() == 0? or cursor == null? etc.

Comment: here's my view:
1) if there's error, pls share the error log.
2) confirm that you query statement is runnable/returns result in sqlite itself. u can extract the .db file (root device) and open it in a sqlite browser. 
3) make sure u really have data in the database, try doing a select * from airport limit 10 and see if your cursor.size() has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was closing the database connection before reading the data out of the Cursor. Apparently you can't do that. Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the column names u are giving is correct...

Comment: If the column names were not correct would the SQL I copied from the cursor using the debugger run properly?